# How this line works? Kindly help me

Tags: c++

I want to know the meaning of this line in linked list in C++.

`i = (i == NULL)? Head : i->Next;`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yeah it's a nice question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i = (i == NULL)? Head : i->Next;
```

This is ternary operator.

```
If i is NULL
   then i = Head
else
   i = i->Next
```